# Swift CodeUnit to String

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode

As stated in Apple Docs:

> An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point
>
> `let dollarSign = "\u{24}"        // $,  Unicode scalar U+0024`

my question is if I have the hexadecimal digit how could I turn it into string. So if I have the following :

`let dollarSignHex = 24`

How can I map it to `let dollarSignString = ????`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`24` is a *decimal* integer constant. If you want the Unicode code point
with the *hexadecimal* number 24 then you have to start with

```
let dollarCode = 0x24
```

or

```
let dollarCode = 36
```

Then you can create a string from that integer value with

```
let dollarSignString = String(UnicodeScalar(dollarCode)) // $
```

Alternatively, start with a *string* containing the hexadecimal
representation of the code point, and convert that to a number
and then to a string:

```
let dollarSignHex = "24"
let dollarCode = UInt32(dollarSignHex, radix: 16)! // 36
let dollarSignString = String(UnicodeScalar(dollarCode)) // $
```